# The Minion Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I need some help with the code for the below Minion Game:
Kevin and Stuart want to play the 'The Minion Game'.

Game Rules

Both players are given the same string,
Both players have to make substrings using the letters of the string.
Stuart has to make words starting with consonants.
Kevin has to make words starting with vowels.
The game ends when both players have made all possible substrings.

```
def minion_game(string):
    # your code goes here
    n = len(string)
    comb = ((n)*(n+1))/2
    count_k = 0
    count_s = 0
    count_k = sum([len(string[i:]) for i in range(len(string)) if string[i] in "AEIOU"])
    count_s = comb - count_k
    
    if count_s == count_k:
        print("Draw")
    elif count_s > count_k:
        print("Stuart", int(count_s) )
    else:
        print("Kevin", int(count_k))
```

This satisfied all Test cases except one due to the time limit exceed, can someone help me to simplify this code?

Comment: This code doesn't really do what the instructions say, you just sum the length of the substrings that starts with vowels in the original string, not all the combinations.

Comment: it does checks all the possible combination sub-string and then subtracts the substring starting with a vowel from the total which gives consonants substring. Then calculate the winner.  Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: For starters you don't check all the combinations. For example for `'ASD'` you check only `'ASD'`, but the combinations are `['ASD', 'ADS', 'SAD', 'SDA', 'DAS', 'DSA']`.

Comment: Thanks for the input :).
I have edited the code and simplified it to reach the results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
len(string[i:])
```

This takes `string`, makes a copy of a substring of it, and then throws away that copy. Since you know that `n` is the length of the whole string and that `string[i:]` is the string, but starting at position `i`, you know that `len(string[i:])` is `n - i`. So replace that unnecessary string copy with `n - i`.

Comment: Ok understood! let me try that out. Thanks i ll update the results

Comment: Hi, here is the code that satisfied all the test case
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = 'AEIOU'
    str_lenght = len(string)
    kevin_score, stuart_score = 0, 0

    for i in range(str_lenght):
        if string[i] in vowels:
            kevin_score += (str_lenght - i)
        else:
            stuart_score += (str_lenght - i)

    if kevin_score > stuart_score:
        print("Kevin", kevin_score)
    elif kevin_score < stuart_score:
        print("Stuart", stuart_score)
    else:
        print("Draw")